# Is there any blade compatible html to pdf converter for php?

Tags: laravel-5, pdf-generation, template-engine, laravel-blade, dompdf

I have tried dompdf but no luck !

I am using blade template engine with laravel 5 , i want to convert a html file created using blade template engine.

I have used dompdf , tested it with blade syntax , but it throws errors . But when i input normal html page in it , it works and converts the html code to pdf properly.

Please suggest me any html to pdf converter which is blade compatible!

Please help guys :)

```
<body class="homepage skin-blue fixed">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
    <div class="header1">
        <div class="slider1">
            <li class="cards">
                <span class="closeFeedback"></span>

            <li class="heading_orange"><a>Heading</a></li>
            <li>
                <ul class="inline_text">

                    <li>
                        <a>AZ</a>
                        <a><p>FLAG</p></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>{{$data->er->name}}</a>
                        <a>
                            {!!Form::select('tenure',$data->terms,$data->id,array('class'=>'form-control tenure','style'=>'margin-left: -6%;margin-top: -5%;width: 112%'));!!}
                        </a>
                        <a>Marks <span class="list_number">2</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>             

            </li>
            <li class="councillor_box bgcolor_faintwhite "><a>Age <span class="list_number">{{$data->age}}</span></a></li>

            <li class="bgcolor_lightblue bgcolor_faintwhite"><a class="text_align_left">Questions Asked</a>
                <ul>
                    @foreach($data->question_count as $question)
                    <li class="box_border"><a>{{$question->name}}<span class="list_number">{{$question->count}}</span></a></li>
                    @endforeach
                    <li class="box_border see_more" type="questionAsked"><a>See more</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="bgcolor_faintwhite bgcolor_lightblue"><a class="text_align_left">Money Spent</a>
                <ul>
                    @foreach($data->money_spent_count as $money)
                    <li class="box_border"><a>{{$money->name}}<span class="list_number">{{$money->actual_spent_amount}}</span></a></li>
                    @endforeach
                    <li class="box_border see_more" type="moneySpent"><a>See more</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="bgcolor_faintwhite bgcolor_lightblue"><a>Attendance <b class="heading_number_councillor_attendance">65%</b></a>
                <ul>
                    <li id="third_level_first"><a class="light_orange">2015 <b>65%</b></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a class=" bg_light_orange">General Body Meetings
                                    <span class="text_right">00</span></a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a class=" bg_light_orange">Committee 1
                                    <span class="text_right">00</span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a class=" bg_light_orange">Committee 2
                                    <span class="text_right">00</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>            
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </li>    

            <li class="councillor_box bgcolor_faintwhite bgcolor_lightblue"><a>Issues</a>
                <ul>

                    <li id="third_level_first"><a class="light_orange">Civic 
                        </a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a class=" bg_light_orange tinybox_border">Top Civic Issues</a></li>

                            @if(empty($data->Civic['issue']))
                            <li><a class=" bg_light_orange">None</a></li>
                            @else
                            @foreach($data->Civic['issue'] as $issue)
                            <li class="issues" issue_type = "civic"><a class=" bg_light_orange">{{$issue['name']}}<span class="text_right">{{$issue['count']}}</span></a></li>
                            @endforeach
                            @endif

                            <li id="third_level_second"><a class="amit bg_light_orange text_center">Questions Asked on Civic Issues</a></li>

                            @if(empty($data->Civic['question']))
                            <li><a class=" bg_light_orange">None</a></li>
                            @else
                            @foreach($data->Civic['question'] as $question)
                            <li><a class=" bg_light_orange">{{$question['name']}}<span class="text_right">{{$question['count']}}</span></a></li>
                            @endforeach
                            @endif
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="third_level_first"><a class="light_orange">Health 
                        </a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a class=" bg_light_orange tinybox_border" >Top Diseases/Ailments</a></li>

                            @if(empty($data->Health['issue']))
                            <li><a class=" bg_light_orange">None</a></li>
                            @else
                            @foreach($data->Health['issue'] as $question)
                            <li class="issues" issue_type = "health"><a class=" bg_light_orange">{{$question['name']}}<span class="text_right">{{$question['count']}}</span></a></li>
                            @endforeach
                            @endif

                            <li id="third_level_second"><a class="bg_light_orange text_center">Questions asked on Health</a></li>

                            @if(empty($data->Health['question']))
                            <li><a class=" bg_light_orange">None</a></li>
                            @else
                            @foreach($data->Health['question'] as $question)
                            <li><a class=" bg_light_orange">{{$question['name']}}<span class="text_right">{{$question['count']}}</span></a></li>
                            @endforeach
                            @endif
                        </ul>
                    </li>


                    <li id="third_level_first"><a class="light_orange">Education 
                        </a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a class=" bg_light_orange tinybox_border" >Statistics</a></li>

                            @if(empty($data->Education['issue']))
                            <li><a class=" bg_light_orange">None</a></li>
                            @else
                            @foreach($data->Education['issue'] as $question)
                            <li class="issues" issue_type = "education"><a class=" bg_light_orange">{{$question['name']}}<span class="text_right">{{$question['count']}}</span></a></li>
                            @endforeach
                            @endif

                            <li id="third_level_second"><a class="bg_light_orange text_center">Questions Asked on Education</a></li>

                            @if(empty($data->Education['question']))
                            <li><a class=" bg_light_orange">None</a></li>
                            @else
                            @foreach($data->Education['question'] as $question)
                            <li><a class=" bg_light_orange">{{$question['name']}}<span class="text_right">{{$question['count']}}</span></a></li>
                            @endforeach
                            @endif
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li id="third_level_first"><a class="light_orange">Other 
                        </a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a class=" bg_light_orange tinybox_border" >Issues</a></li>

                            @if(empty($data->Crime['issue']))
                            <li><a class=" bg_light_orange">None</a></li>
                            @else
                            @foreach($data->Crime['issue'] as $question)
                            <li class="issues" issue_type = "crime"><a class=" bg_light_orange">{{$question['name']}}<span class="text_right">{{$question['count']}}</span></a></li>
                            @endforeach
                            @endif

                            <li id="third_level_second"><a class="bg_light_orange text_center">Questions Asked on Other Issues</a></li>

                            @if(empty($data->Crime['question']))
                            <li><a class=" bg_light_orange">None</a></li>
                            @else
                            @foreach($data->Crime['question'] as $question)
                            <li><a class=" bg_light_orange">{{$question['name']}}<span class="text_right">{{$question['count']}}</span></a></li>
                            @endforeach
                            @endif


                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </li> 
            <li class="bgcolor_faintwhite bgcolor_darkblue"><a >Contact</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="nine_px smallbox_border full_width"><a class=" text_left full_width" >For All Complaints
                            <span class="text_right">1916</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="full_width address_box"><a class=" text_left nine_px" >{{$data->erDetails->address}},{{$data->erDetails->city_name}},{{$data->erDetails->pincode}},{{$data->erDetails->state_name}}</a></li>
                    <li class="contact_social nine_px">

                        <a class=" full_width">WEBSITE</a>
                        <a class=" full_width">F</a>
                        <a class=" full_width">T</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="bgcolor_faintwhite equalbox"><a >Other Councillors From Same Ward (H/W)</a></li>
            <li class="bgcolor_faintwhite equalbox"><a >Other ERs In Constituency</a></li>
            <li class="bgcolor_faintwhite equalbox"><a >Top & Bottom Councillors of Mumbai</a></li>
            <li class="bgcolor_faintwhite equalbox"><a >Download Report Card</a></li>

            <li class="social_network">

                <span class="pad_0px">
                    <a onclick="openShareDialog('facebook', this);" data-link="">Share</a>
                    <a onclick="openShareDialog('twitter', this);" data-link="">Tweet</a>
                    <a class="download">Download</a>
                </span>

            </li>
            </ul>
            </li>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="example-modal">
        <div class="modal" id='message-modal'>
        </div> 
    </div>
</body>
```

This is my php blade view file which is to be downloaded as pdf.

The pdf conversion is as follows

```
$html = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $html = $html->loadHtml(view('cards.pdf_card',compact('data'))->render());

    return $html->download('card.pdf');
```

The 'data' here is considered to be generated before.

The error is as follows,

```
ErrorException in frame.cls.php line 765:
Argument 1 passed to DOMNode::appendChild() must be an instance of  DOMNode, null given, called in     /opt/lampp/htdocs/brt_praja/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/include/table_frame_decorator.cls.php on line 312 and defined
```

Thanks in advance for some help.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried to convert your blade template with dompdf? You have to render the blade template as html (using `view('template')->render()`) before converting it.

Comment: Also, it would help to see the errors.

Comment: I have added the code of view and pdf conversion and the following is the error